# How to create OTP using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

How to create OTP using Angular JS when user enter mobile number , need to pass otp to backend and authenticate with users OTP.

Comment: @Priyanka Tinkle You need to update your Interesting Query with your research and  what you understood so far .. this things will give you soo many views which can result to good answers :-) please update it ..

Comment: @Priya Tinkle : please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score -1):

Script tag to AngularJS, assign values0-9a-zA-Z, get length of this variable, init, loop, use Math.floor(Math.random() * variable length), return result

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).